# Excel VBA - Selecting Columns dynamically using Column headers

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to select a column dynamically based on the Column headers in VBA. This is the code that I am using ,

```
Sub trial()

Dim colm As Long
Dim nwb As Workbook, wb As Workbook
Dim nwk As Worksheet, wk As Worksheet, wk1 As Worksheet

co1m = WorksheetFunction.Match("Header", Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(1), 0)

Columns(colm).Select

End Sub
```

when I try to debug it, it shows the value of 5 in colm and at the same time on the next line columns(colm).select, it shows 0 in the place of colm. Kindly help me with where I am going wrong in this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in there! You have `co1m` and `colm`.

Using `Option Explicit` would have throw a compile error saying that `co1m` wasn't declared! ;)

```
Option Explicit

Sub trial()

Dim colm As Long
Dim nwb As Workbook, wb As Workbook
Dim nwk As Worksheet, wk As Worksheet, wk1 As Worksheet

colm = WorksheetFunction.Match("Header", Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(1), 0)

Columns(colm).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @R3uK. I am not sure its the typo that I had in the code because I looked in the code it wasn't a typo but when I added this Option Explicit, it just started working. Is there any reason behind this Option Explicit? Thanks again buddy !!

Comment: @VBA_Begineer : `Option Explicit` is just a best practice (you can set VBE to use it by default, check in the options) to avoid that kind of error, it'll force you to declare all the variable there is in your code, and so it'll warn you when you have a typo! ;) Please accept the answer as this solved your issue.

Comment: @R3_uK Thanks mate. I was made to wait for 10 minutes by Stack Overflow to accept your answer. Sorry for that. Thanks again !!

Comment: @VBA_Begineer : Ahaha NP, I forgot about that limitation! ;)